# nl2br function producing whitespace after newline

Tags: php, nl2br

The following code produces a whitespace after each newline and I don't know why. Please help, how can I make the same functionality without adding whitespaces?

```
<?php

$test =  "Hello World\nHello World";
$test = preg_replace ( "/([^\s]{80}?)/" , "\\1<br />" , trim ( nl2br ( strip_tags ( $test, '<br>' ) ) ) );
echo $test;`

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the test and I didn't notice any whitespace after the use of the `nl2br()` function.

```php
$string =  "Hello World\nHello World";
$string = nl2br ($string);
```

Output

```
Hello World<br />\n
Hello World
```

It is worth noting that this function preserves the newlines.